# Was ist eine Lohhucke?

Tags: meaning

Im grimmschen Märchen [„Die Rabe“](http://www.maerchenlexikon.de/Grimm/khm-texte/khm093.htm) taucht das Wort Lohhucke mehrfach auf. Das erste Auftreten ist an dieser Wortstelle:

[image: Im Garten hinter dem Haus ist eine große Lohhucke, darauf sollst du stehen und mich erwarten.]

Der Text im Wortlaut für die Suchmaschine und jene, die das Bild oben nicht sehen können:

> Im Garten hinter dem Haus ist eine große Lohhucke, darauf sollst du
>   stehen und mich erwarten.

Wiktionary erwähnt die Lohhucke [unter Hucke](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hucke), aber macht keine Angaben zum Wortteil "Loh-". [Auf Wikipedia wird gemutmaßt,](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Die_Rabe&oldid=147440541) es handele sich um einen Holzhaufen:

> Die Lohhucke ist offenbar ein Holzhaufen (vgl. Hucke in KHM 90).

[Diese Webseite](http://www.joern.de/DieRabe.htm) schlägt in dieselbe Kerbe und mutmaßt, es handele sich um irgendein brennbares Material oder Asche:

> Zur Hucke, die dort vorkommt – die »Lohhucke« leitet sich wohl eher
>   von der Bedeutung Hucke als Erdhaufen ab: »hucke, im wasserbau,
>   hervorstehende ecke eines deiches oder vorlandes« (Grimmsches
>   Wörterbuch). Ob der Erdhaufen aus »Lohe« bestand, aus Asche oder
>   festem Brennmaterial wie Torf, wer mag es wissen?

Was bezeichnete denn eine Lohhucke genau zu Zeiten der Brüder Grimm? Ich nehme an, mit etwas Kenntnis über Gehöfte zu dieser Zeit könnte man sich dem Problem nähern. Leider habe ich dazu keinerlei Wissen.

Comment: Ich habe es als Laubhaufen interpretiert, bin aber an mehr Informationen sehr interessiert!

Comment: *Holzhaufen* ist mMn an sich schon richtig, aber nicht im Sinne von aufgestapelten Holzscheiten, sondern Anzünd- und Abfallholz (Rinde und Zweige)

Comment: @tofro: hast du Quellen dafür?

Comment: Nä. Aber wörtlich in ein heutiges Wort übersetzt, ergibt sich "Haufen (Holzabfall-)Zeugs zum Verbrennen"

Comment: Hat das was mit (es brennt) „lichterloh” zu tun?

Answer (score 4):

[Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GH12791#XGH12791) definiert *Hucke* als ein Haufen Heu oder Getreide, und in den weiteren Ausführungen wird klar, dass es eine eher kleine Menge sein muss, die man auf einmal tragen konnte.

*Loh-* würde ich so deuten, dass dieser Haufen zum Verbrennen dienen soll; da das Verbrennen von Getreide nicht wirklich plausibel ist (jenseits einer Demonstration von Landwirten, die gegen zu geringe Preise demonstrieren), passt der Heuhaufen besser. Dazu passt auch die Defintion von [Lohballen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/displayLinkInfo.tcl?sigle=DWB&formid=GL06607) aus dem Grimm
Da es im weiteren Verlauf des Märchens heißt:

> .. lag er auch da auf der Lohhucke und schlief

würde ich den Holzhaufen nicht ernsthaft in Betracht ziehen, weil der weder besonders stabil ist noch so bequem, dass man darauf schlafen möchte. Dass man auf Asche schläft, kann ich mir für die damaligen Zeit nicht vorstellen.

Mein Schlussfolgerung: ein eher kleiner Heuhaufen zum Verbrennen (Anfeuern eines Herds oder Ofens).

Comment: Wenn du einen Ofen zuhause hättest, wüsstest du, dass man den mit Heu nicht vernünftig anzünden kann.

Comment: Unter _Lohe_ versteht man auch zum Gerben verwendete Baumrinde oder Blätter. Das würde dann gut passen, Lohhucke = Laub- (oder Rinden-) haufen.

Comment: @Ingmar: paßt zur Bedeutung *lohe, f. rinde, welche die gerber zum garmachen der häute brauchen* im DWB. Baumrinde stelle ich mir nicht allzu bequem vor, aber je nach Kleidung sollte es dennoch gehen.

Comment: Ich würde den Holzstapel nicht ausschließen, oder jedenfalls nicht mit dem  Argument des Unbequemseins. Brennholz muss, um zu trocknen, bekannterweise nach dem Schlagen erst einmal gelagert werden möglichst ein ganzes Jahr lang, und dazu schichtet man die Scheite in der Regel sauber auf - entweder in Form eines langen Riegels oder in Form eines hohen Meilers oder Zuckerhuts. Dies tut man so, dass Regenwasser ab-, aber nicht hineinläuft. Ein solcher Stapel kann durchaus eine gute Liegefläche bieten.Und er ist stabil.

Answer (score 4):

"Lohhucke = woodpile? Possibly “Loh” (wood) + “Hucke” (pile).

- The **Etymologisches Wörterbuch** states that “Loh” dates from the 10th century and means “small forest,” or “wood.”
- The **Grimms DWb** also states a “Hucke” can be several things. A pile of cereals or hay, a load carried on the back, also the bundle carried by a peddler, a protruding corner of a dike, or even a cloak. So “Lohhucke” is possibly a pile of wood or wood pile. In modern German, a “wood pile” is a “Holzhaufen” = ”Holz” (wood) + ”Haufen” (pile).
- The **Deutsches Textarchiv** lists only this text (Die Rabe) as a reference for the word. There is no entry for this exact word in any other of the usual dictionaries. There is another possibility listed in the Deutsches Wörterbuch where “Loh” is the removed bark from oak trees used in tanning anmal skins. In either case, “wood pile” can apply. “Bark pile” is another possibility. Another possibility is listed in the Grimms DWb where “Loh” or “Lohe” is “seething embers.” Lexer and others also describes it as “flame.”
- The **Goethe-Wörterbuch** describes it as “*large, high blazing flame, flame*.”

While “loh” as “embers” or “flame” does not seem too appropriate here, the word “loh” and the releasing of the maiden reminds all too much on Sigurds freeing of Brynhild by going through the fire. Here, it is not likely that the man should stand in a fire, but at some point in the past, the story could have meant this and used this word – “loh” or “lohe.” Then later the association with “fire” was removed and replaced with the “Glasberg,” which can also symbolize “fire.” But this is as far as I want to go in interpreting and I only do it in order to try and clarify what “Lohhucke” actually is. The use of the word is too coincidental not to have been related to “fire” in some way. It is also possible that the word illustrates some of the linguistic archaelogy present in the texts. A word that meant “seething embers” changed meaning over time to be known later as “a pile of wood.”

Hunt in her 1884 translation of the text wrote it as “tanbark.” While it is a possibility, there is no indication in the text that the location is a tannery. Both Manheim and Zipes follow Hunt’s lead and they both also write it as “tanbark.”"

Excerpted from my upcoming translation of the Grimms 1815 first edition of the Kinder und Hausmärchen Volume II by Oliver Loo.

Comment: Wer soll diesen unstrukturierten Worthaufen lesen? Bitte editiere deine Antwort und teile sie in mehrere Absätze auf, damit sie lesbar wird. Generell (für alle Textsorten) gilt: Jeder Absatz führt am Beginn eine neue Idee ein, die dann innerhalb des Absatzes behandelt wird. Als Faustregel für Texte im Internet gilt: Ein Absatz enthält ca. 4 bis 5 Zeilen.

Comment: Wenn möglich, solltest du auf eine Frage, die auf Deutsch gestellt wird, auch auf Deutsch antworten. Siehe https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487